# Why is time complexity of recursive tree equal to number of leaf nodes instead of total number of nodes?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, binary-tree, big-o

I'm looking at the time and space complexity of the simple recursive function below:

[image]

It has time complexity O(2^n), which is the number of leaf nodes. But there is a function call at every node of the tree. Why is the time complexity equal to the number of leaf nodes and not the total number of nodes?

Comment: Because actual work is done only at leaves ( n <= 1 ) and remaining is just popping off the stack (O(1))

Comment: At the leaves it executes `return;` and at the non-leaves it executes `dib(n-1);`. Why does the first count as real work and the other doesn't? Also, Re "popping off the stack", do you mean that when a node executes `dib(n-1)` it pops something off the stack? What exactly is being pushed and popped?

Answer (score 2):

the tree has a depth of 5 and 16 leaf nodes, last time i checked 2^5 is 32 not 16....
it's 2^n because there are 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ... +  2^1 nodes which comes to exactly 2^n-1 calls, discarding the -1 you get O(2^n)

Comment: Understood, thanks. `SomeDude` commented on my original post and said the internal nodes don't count because actual work is only done at the leaves. Which is it?

Comment: well obviously i think im right since i posted this as an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't change the complexity if you count only the leaves or all nodes.

All non leave-Nodes are `2^n-1`.
`O(2^n + 2^n-1) = O(2^n)`.

Comment: Gotcha. The other commenter said the internal nodes don't count because actual work is only done at the leaves. Which is it?